# Postgresql update on character varying column empties it

Tags: java, windows, postgresql, jdbc

I am using PostgreSQL jdbc driver to update a table. It contains several columns, one of them represents the path to the record data file, named `Path` of type `character varying`. Whenever the path changes, the record is updated by calling `updatePath()` on the record class.

What happens is that it *usually* fails and replaces the `Path` value with an empty string. But *sometimes* it works. Of course, if I try the query on pgAdmin it runs fine...
Creating the record with a path always works fine, and updating the whole record (i.e. all columns) updates all columns correctly (including other character varying columns) *except* the `Path` column!

Here is my `update()` method:

```
public static final String IDCOL = "_ID_"; // Primary key, auto-increment
public static final String tableName = "MyTable"; // Table name

private int id; // The record ID
...
private String path; // Path to the record

public boolean updatePath(Connection cnx) {
    String sql = "UPDATE \""+tableName+"\" SET \"Path\"=? WHERE \""+IDCOL+"\"="+id;
    try (PreparedStatement ps = cnx.prepareStatement(sql)) {
        ps.setString(1, path);
        log.debug("<sql>"+ps+"</sql>");
        ps.executeUpdate();
        return true;
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        log.error("Unable to update path: "+e.getMessage());
        return false;
    }
}
```

My debug log shows:

```
UPDATE "MyTable" SET "Path"='\\192.168.1.10\Store\2016 04\data73849.dat' WHERE "_ID_"=73849
```

Can it be that the `\` character in the path are somehow (mis)interpreted by Postgres?

Comment: Very unlikely, but you could test your hypothesis by doing `replace('\\', '/')` on the value, so no backslashes are present (for testing only, of course). If you can prove that to be the case, report a bug.

Comment: @Andreas, I'll try that, thanks.

Comment: Backslashes should only be recognized if you either use escape strings (PG extension) or if standard_conforming_strings is set to off (see http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/interactive/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-STRINGS).

Comment: @Andreas it seems it's working a lot better with `/` instead of `\` (for a reason yet to be determined). I'll switch back to `\` for confirmation.